# Duplicate data from firebase realtime databse

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

There is a method that adds data to my list from the firebase realtime database:

```
private fun getTargetsFromDb() {
        val uid = firebaseUser!!.uid
        val targetsRef = databaseReference?.child("targets")?.child("users")?.child(uid)?.child("targets")
        val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (targetSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val target = targetSnapshot.getValue(Target::class.java)
                    target?.let { targetList.add(it) }
                }
                recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("some", "Error trying to get targets for ${databaseError.message}")
            }
        }
        targetsRef?.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
    }
```

But sometimes when I jump from fragment to fragment, I have a duplicate list of data.

Q: I need somewhere to `remove` the data for the `targetList`?

Comment: you can clear list before adding the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can help you to clear the old data and store the new one in list.

```
private fun getTargetsFromDb() {
        val uid = firebaseUser!!.uid
        val targetsRef = databaseReference?.child("targets")?.child("users")?.child(uid)?.child("targets")
        val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                targetList.clear()
                for (targetSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val target = targetSnapshot.getValue(Target::class.java)
                    target?.let { targetList.add(it) }
                }
                recyclerView?.adapter = adapter
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("some", "Error trying to get targets for ${databaseError.message}")
            }
        }
        targetsRef?.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
    }
```

Above code will check if response is successful then it will clear list and store the values or it won't clear the list and just give you exception.